# How to fill data in a JTable with database?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to display a JTable that display the data from a DataBase table as it is.

Up till now, I have used JTable that displays data from Object [ ][ ].

I know one way to display the data is to first convert the database table into Object [ ][ ] but Is there any other which is easy yet more powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would recommend taking the following approach:

- Create a `Row` class to represent a row read from your `ResultSet`.  This could be a simple wrapper around an `Object[]`.
- Create a `List<Row>` collection, and subclass `AbstractTableModel` to be backed by this collection.
- Use a `SwingWorker` to populate your `List<Row>` by reading from the underlying `ResultSet` on a **background thread** (i.e. within the `doInBackground()` method).  Call `SwingWorker`'s `publish` method to publish `Row`s back to the Event Dispatch thread (e.g. every 100 rows).
- When the `SwingWorker`'s `process` method is called with the latest chunk of Rows read, add them to your `List<Row>` and fire appropriate `TableEvent`s to cause the display to update.
- Also, use the `ResultSetMetaData` to determine the `Class` of each column within the `TableModel` definition.  This will cause them to be rendered correctly (which won't be the case if you simply use a 2D `Object[][]` array).

The advantage of this approach is that the UI will not lock up when processing large `ResultSet`s, and that the display will update incrementally as results are processed.

**EDIT**

Added example code below:

```
/**
 * Simple wrapper around Object[] representing a row from the ResultSet.
 */
private class Row {
  private final Object[] values;

  public Row(Object[] values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return values.length;
  }

  public Object getValue(int i) {
    return values[i];
  }
}

// TableModel implementation that will be populated by SwingWorker.
public class ResultSetTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private final ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
  private final List<Row> rows;

  public ResultSetTableModel(ResultSetMetaData rsmd) {
    this.rsmd = rsmd;
    this.rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return rows.size();
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return rsmd.getColumnCount();
  }

  public Object getValue(int row, int column) {
    return rows.get(row).getValue(column);
  }

  public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return rsmd.getColumnName(col - 1); // ResultSetMetaData columns indexed from 1, not 0.
  }

  public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
    // TODO: Convert SQL type (int) returned by ResultSetMetaData.getType(col) to Java Class.
  }
}

// SwingWorker implementation
new SwingWorker<Void, Row>() {
  public Void doInBackground() {
    // TODO: Process ResultSet and create Rows.  Call publish() for every N rows created.
  }

  protected void process(Row... chunks) {
    // TODO: Add to ResultSetTableModel List and fire TableEvent.
  }
}.execute();
```

Comment: I have got your answer but still have some confusions in my mind. Could be please specify with a small code snippet.

Comment: I have mentioned my problem as a comment on my new question.

Answer (score 7):

Another powerful and flexible way to display database data in a JTable is to load your query's resulting data into a [CachedRowSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html), then connect it to the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) with [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) adapter.

1. Query ---> Database data ---> RowSet
2. RowSet <--> TableModel adapter <--> JTable

This [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926165/) by George Reese gives [the source code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/RowSetModelbasedonTableModelJTable.htm) for his class *RowSetModel* to adapt a [RowSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) as a TableModel. Worked for me out-of-the-box. My only change was a better name for the class: *RowSetTableModel*.

A RowSet is a subinterface of ResultSet, added in Java 1.4. So a RowSet *is* a ResultSet.

A CachedRowSet implementation does the work for you, instead of you creating a Row class, a List of Row objects, and ResultSetMetaData as discussed in other answers on this page.

Sun/Oracle provides a [reference implementation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.html) of CachedRowSet. Other vendors or JDBC drivers may provide implementations as well.

[RowSet tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/chapter5.html)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you've done already and what you're willing to do, I've been using Netbeans with its Beans Binding support for a database-driven app very successfully. You bind your JTable to a database and it automatically builds the JPA queries.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to fill jTable with ResultSet

### Prerequisites

1) Result Set "rs" is populated with data you need.
2) JTable "jTable1" is created before hand
3) Table Header is implemented before hand

### Implementation

```
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = datacn.executeSelectQuery(query);
        //Filling JTable with Result set

        // Removing Previous Data
        while (jTable1.getRowCount() > 0) {
            ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }

        //Creating Object []rowData for jTable's Table Model        
        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next())
        {  
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {  
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i); // 1
            }
            ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1,row);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a custom [TableModel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) There you can specify where and how the data is coming from.

You really have to fully understand first how [JTable](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) + [TableModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) works and then follow one of the previously posted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but for anyone following Adamski's solution, care should be taken while sharing the `ResultSet` and `ResultSetMetadata` between gui and `SwingWorker` threads. I got an inconsistent internal state exception while using this approach with SQLite. The solution is to load any metadata to private fields before executing the `SwingWorker` and have the getter functions (getColumnName etc.) to return the fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a small method for display database table data in JTable. You need to pass only the resultset of the database table as parameter.

```
    // rs is the ResultSet of the Database table
    public void displayData(ResultSet rs)
    {
        //jt Represents JTable
        //jf represents JFrame
        int i;
        int count;
        String a[];
        String header[] = {"1","2","3","4","5"};   //Table Header Values, change, as your wish
        count = header.length;
```

//First set the Table header
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        model.addColumn(header[i]);
    }
    jt.setModel(model);                             //Represents table Model
    jf.add(jt.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH);

    a = new String[count];

    // Adding Database table Data in the JTable
    try
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                a[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
            }
            model.addRow(a);                //Adding the row in table model
            jt.setModel(model);             // set the model in jtable
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception : "+e, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

Comment: I know this answer is old but what is model?

Comment: model is the object of TableModel