# JTable swing import database sql

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, jtable

Could someone provide me with an example or tutorial on how to import a data from a mysql database within a JTable within the use of a GUI. I tried looking for an example but have not found anything.

Comment: This question has only been asked and answered 1000 times before. Since you state that previous examples haven't helped but don't tell us how or why they don't help, or what you've tried or how it doesn't work, I doubt that any of our answers will help you any more than they did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill data in a JTable with database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192764/how-to-fill-data-in-a-jtable-with-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully we can put this question to rest

```
Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection( jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.3:3306,<user>,<password>);
Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DB");
ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();

// get column names
int len = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
Vector cols= new Vector(len);
for(int i=1; i<=len; i++) // Note starting at 1
    cols.add(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));


// Add Data
Vector data = new Vector();
while(rs.next())
{
    Vector row; = new Vector(len);
    for(int i=1; i<=len; i++)
    {
        row.add(rs.getString(i));
    }
    data.add(row);
}

// Now create the table
JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
```