# How to get selected rows from a database into a jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a database table which has many patient details like registration id, registration date etc. I want to perform a date based search of the patients and get the result into a jTable. ( for example, if I type 23-05-2013 as the registration date, all the patients admitted on 23 May should be displayed in a jTable. How do I do that?

This is the code I have used:

```
public void getTableData() {
  try {
     con = getConnection.getCon();
     String sql = "SELECT * FROM patientrecords WHERE Registration Date = ?";
     pst.setString(1, regdate.getText());
     pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     rs = pst.executeQuery();
     if (rs.next()) {
        patient_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
     }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited your post to fix the all caps in the title. Please don't do that. Also, please slow down and take your time writing your question. When it's neat and readable, people will take you more seriously. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer now im thinking that his code may be works xD

Answer (score 2):

1) You should make your own `TableModel` implementation or extending `AbstractTableModel`

2) Map `patientrecords` to object world. Also entity name should be in singular. So you will have a java-bean like `PatientRecord`.

3) You'll have a `List<PatientRecord> data` as DataHolder.

Fill like

```
while (rs.next()) {
        data.add(new PatientRecord(..));
}
```

4) In some part you should set in your `jtable.setModel(..)`

This previous question may help you [simple code to populate jtable from resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset)