# JTable not showing data

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdbc

I have got a problem. I connect mssql from java. I return data from sql.I want to show jtable this data but I didnt assign jtable from DefaultTableModel.
My code:

```
public void displayTable(ResultSet result,ResultSetMetaData resultMeta){
    int i;
    DefaultTableModel table = new DefaultTableModel(); 
    int columnCount=resultMeta.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println(columnCount);
   try{
    for(i=1;i<=columnCount;i++)
        table.addColumn(resultMeta.getColumnName(i));

    while(result.next()){
            String [] row=new String[columnCount];
            for(int j=1;j<=columnCount;j++)
                row[j-1]=result.getString(j);
            table.addRow(row);
       }    
    for(int a =0;a<columnCount;a++){
   System.out.println(table.getColumnName(a));
    }
    tablo.setModel(table);

  }catch(Exception ex){ System.out.println(ex);  }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? What is your question?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See [_Most simple code to populate JTable from ResultSet_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10625471/870248)