# Get information of Mysql table's structure in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am doing a project and I need to find some information of any given table of mysql. I need names of columns and their attributes such if any of them is index or not.
I'm doing this in Java, how can I get this piece of info about any table?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JDBC, you can get that with:

```
String tableNamePattern = "customer";
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = conn.getMetaData();

ResultSet columns = 
       databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableNamePattern, null);

ResultSet primaryKeys = 
       databaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tableNamePattern);

ResultSet indexInfo = 
       databaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(null, null, tableNamePattern, false, false);
```

You can see the information, e.g. using [Most simple code to populate JTable from ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset/10625471#10625471).

Comment: Thank you to answer me but how about attributes?

Comment: Ok ... I think i've got my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good as an example:
http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-Column-List.html