# JTable not being populated from resultset with DButils

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

I've been trying to get a handle on how to populate a jtable with data from my resultset and have found out that using DBUtils is probably the easiest method but unfortunately its not working for me at all. The program runs but the jtable remains empty as ever. I don't understand where I'm going wrong with it. I have import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils; imported at the top and the jar added in class path. Here is my code:

```
private void jPanel3FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                    

    // TODO add your handling code here:

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/new";

//  Database credentials
String USER = "root";
String PASS = "";

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
try{
  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  //STEP 3: Open a connection
  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

  //STEP 4: Execute a query
  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
  String sql;
  sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  //Bind values into the parameters.
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

  jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
 }
    catch (SQLException ex) {

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
 }
catch(Exception e){
  //Handle errors for Class.forName
  e.printStackTrace();
 }


finally {

try {

  stmt.close();
  conn.close();

} 
catch (SQLException e) { /* ignore */

}



try {

    conn.close();

} catch (SQLException e) { /* ignore */

 }
}
 }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Dang I got it working. Apparently there was nothing wrong with the code but the Action event FocusGained was not working for some reason. Used a button press action event and the same code worked. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

I got stucked on the same point,
So I used ***"Vectors"***

We all know using Arraylist is much better approach when considering the implementations of Vectors.But when working with **jTables**, by default you got some easy methods to mange the data flow and fill into the jTable which will ease the coding.
So if you have less experiance in coding these scenarios like me, I suggest to use **Vectors**.

Just have to import this and bit of code.

**import java.util.Vector;**

To learn, how to use Vectors to work with **ResultSet** refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset)

Comment: *"Check that you put Class.forName()"* put where? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The OP stated that the code worked fine.  Check the comments.

Comment: danthaaa  I think OP code is working see comments on the question

Comment: Yes ,It works by using "jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));"                            But you will learn nothing if use DBUtils class, That's y I put this post to understand the real scenario for the beginners like me. :)