# Filling up cell when clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable

First of all thanks for your support. I'm creating an application with MySQL database to store User details (Names, Age..). Just want to send the Name value to a `JTable` cell clicked by the user.

I'm able to store the value in a String, and show it in `System.out.println`,  but cannot fill the cell up with the value.

Is this possible any how?

Comment: have a loot at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset

Comment: Please add some code ;)

Comment: Rahul, I'm not trying to fill the jTable directly with database values. It is simpler, just wanted to fill a particular cell with a String value, once the user clicked the cell:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm able to store the value in a String, and show it in System.out.println, but cannot fill the cell up with the value.*

It is unclear how do you get this String and what have you tried but you can use `setValueAt(...)` method to set this String as the selected cell's value. In order to get the selected cell row and column indexes you should use `getSelectedRow()` and `getSelectedColumn()` methods, respectively. Finally to detect user's "click" you have to attach a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the table or a [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) to the table's [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) to listen for selection changes.

See the API:

- [JTable#setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setValueAt-java.lang.Object-int-int-)
- [JTable#getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow--)
- [JTable#getSelectedColumn()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumn--)

See also:

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it with this code:
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
    jTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = target.getSelectedRow();
        int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
        
        jTable1.getCellSelectionEnabled();
       
        target.setValueAt(jTextField2.getText(), row, column);