# JTable with custome CellRenderer, really laggy and freezy while scrolling

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer

First of all, i searched the whole day, tried many solutions, but no one worked..

I want to have line wrapping in my jtable.. so I made my own cellrenderer... but my JTable is laggy while scrolling etc...

Here is my cellrenderer:

```
public class LineWrapCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer{


public LineWrapCellRenderer(){


      this.setWrapStyleWord(true);            
        this.setLineWrap(true);   
        this.setOpaque(true);


}
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column) {


     if (value != null) {
            setText(value.toString());
          } else {
            setText("");
          }

        return this;
    }

}
```

I've set the renderer with

```
setDefaultRenderer(String.class, CellRenderer);
```

My tablemodel looks like this:

```
return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){

    Object tempRetVal = new Object();
    Object RetVal = new Object();


     @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }



    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {

        tempRetVal = Object.class;
        RetVal = Object.class;


        if(getRowCount() > 0){

            for(int i = 0; i<getRowCount();i++){
                tempRetVal =  getValueAt(i, columnIndex);



            if(tempRetVal!=null){
                RetVal = tempRetVal;
            }
            }
        }
        return RetVal.getClass();
    }

};
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Your lags from `getColumnClass()` method , why do you always need to loop through rows?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to get the data type of the column. But sometimes the first cell is empty.. so I loop through the whole rows of a column to get the data type..

Comment: Do you store different types in one column? If data have same type set column classes when create model.

Comment: No, I dont store different types in one column. But the tablemodel is created with a Resultset, dynamically.. the probelm is, if I just ckeck the first row of a column, it is maybe empty, so Object.class will be returned and my renderer wont be used, althoug the column is from type string and other rows of that column contain strings

Comment: Seems [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10625471/2894369) helps you.

Comment: I already made it like that :D

Comment: So,you can get column types from resultSet Metadata, and you needn't to get it from rows

Comment: Thanks, i changed it, but it is stll laggy... the resutlset is about 1000 rows big.. is that a problem to have so much textareas in the jtable?

Comment: `is that a problem to have so much textareas in the jtable?` - There is only one text area. That is the reason for using a renderer. It is easy to test. Just remove your custom renderer and see what scrolling is like using the default renderer (which is a JLabel).

Comment: Creating a text area renderer is not that simple. You also need to manage the size of the cell. If you want to display all the text, then you need to set the height of each row in the table. Or if you only want to display 2 lines of text and then let then user scroll you can't just use a renderer because the renderer is not a real component so scrollbars won't work. Anyway, here is an old solution that may or may not help: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue106.html

Comment: When I comment 

   `setDefaultRenderer(String.class, CellRenderer);`

It isnt laggy any more