# Display ResultSet of a SQL query in a JTable (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, resultset

I'm working on a program with which I can search through a database and display the results.

I'm stuck at the displaying part at the moment. My SQL query already works and returns the results. I'm using a PreparedStatement to fill my ResultSet. However I don't know how I can return the data of the ResultSet to a JTable which I want to use to display the data. Can anyone explain to me in detail how to do this or if there is a better way instead of a JTable I'm not seeing?

I'm using the MVC model and the DAO pattern, but I'm still pretty new to programming.
So far from researching it I found the best solution to be to make a custom table class, but from there on I don't know how to progress.

My custom table class:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class ResultSetTable {
 public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();

        //Spaltennamen
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
            columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnLabel(column + 1));
        }

        //Alle Zeilen
        Vector rows = new Vector();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector newRow = new Vector();

            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
            }

            rows.addElement(newRow);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And the relevant part of my View class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import dbconnect.dao.impl.BTRDaoImpl;

public class View extends JFrame{
public View() {

    JTable table = new JTable(new ResultSetTable(BTRDaoImpl.resultset);

    this.setSize(600, 400);
    setResizable(false);
}
```

My BTRDaoImpl class with the sql query and resultset:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import mvc.View;
import dao.BTRbDao;
import business.BTRBean;

public class BTRDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements BTRDao {

private Connection dbConnection = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public void sqlquery() {
    try {

        String btrname = View.searchbbtrname.getText();
        String btrplz = View.searchbtrplz.getText();
        btrname = btrname.trim().toUpperCase();
        btrplz = btrplz.trim().toUpperCase();

        if (btrplz.isEmpty()) {
            String btrResult = "SELECT BBSTBBNR, BBSTNABE, BBSTPLZ FROM BP.TBBBST WHERE BBSTNABEG = ?";

            dbConnection = AbstractDao.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(btrResult);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, btrname);


        } else {
            String btrResult = "SELECT BBSTBBNR, BBSTNABE, BBSTPLZ FROM BP.TBBBST WHERE BBSTNABEG = ? AND BBSTPLZ = ?";

            dbConnection = AbstractDao.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(btrResult);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, btrname);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, btrplz);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("An error with the SQL query occured: ");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public Collection<BtrBean> getBTR() throws SQLException,
        IOException {
    sqlquery();
    final Collection<BtrBean> result = new ArrayList<BtrBean>();

    ResultSet resultset = null;
    try {
        resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        // while loop to get data
        while (resultset.next()) {
            BtrBean btr = new BtrBean();
            int btrid = resultset.getInt(1);
            String btrplz = resultset.getString(3);
            String btrname = resultset.getString(2);
            btr.setBetriebnr(btrid);
            btr.setBetriebplz(btrplz);
            btr.setBetriebname(btrname);
            result.add(btr);
        //  System.out.println("BTR-ID: " + btrid + " BTR PLZ: " + btrplz + " BTR: " + btrname);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("An error processing the SQL occured: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("NullPointerException: ");
        npe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
        closeConnection(resultset);
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

My BTRBean class:

```
public class BetriebBean {

private String betriebname;
private int betriebnr;
private String betriebplz;

public BetriebBean() {

}

public BetriebBean(String betriebname, int betriebnr, String betriebplz) {
    super();
    this.betriebname = betriebname;
    this.betriebnr = betriebnr;
    this.betriebplz = betriebplz;
}
public String getBetriebname() {
    return betriebname;
}
public void setBetriebname(String betriebname) {
    this.betriebname = betriebname;
}
public int getBetriebnr() {
    return betriebnr;
}
public void setBetriebnr(int betriebnr) {
    this.betriebnr = betriebnr;
}
public String getBetriebplz() {
    return betriebplz;
}
public void setBetriebplz(String betriebplz) {
    this.betriebplz = betriebplz;
}

}
```

//edit:

My whole View.class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class View extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String SEARCH = "SEARCH";

private JLabel searchbtrlabel = new JLabel("BTR name:");
public static JTextField searchbtrname = new JTextField(10);
private JLabel searchbtrlabel = new JLabel("PLZ:");
public static JTextField searchbtrplz = new JTextField(10);
private JButton searchbutton = new JButton();

public View() {
    this.setTitle("BTR search TBBBST");

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    this.add(searchbtrlabel);
    this.add(searchbtrname);
    this.add(searchbtrplzlabel);
    this.add(searchbtrplz);

    searchbutton.setText("Search");
    searchbutton.setActionCommand(View.SEARCH);
    this.add(searchbutton);

    JTable table = new JTable();
    this.add(table);

    this.setSize(600, 400);
    setResizable(false);
    //this.pack();
}

public JTextField getSearchbtrname() {
    return searchbetriebname;
}

public JTextField getSearchbbtrplz() {
    return searchbetriebplz;
}

public JButton getSearchbutton() {
    return searchbutton;
}
}
```

My Controller class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import mvc.Model;
import dbconnect.dao.impl.BTRDaoImpl;

public class Controller implements Observer, ActionListener{

private Model model;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private View view;

public Controller(Model model, View view) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

    model.addObserver(this);
    view.getSearchbutton().addActionListener(this);
    view.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
    case View.SEARCH:
        model.search();
        view.table.setModel(ResultSetToTable.buildTableModel(BTRDaoImpl.resultset));
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Error : " + e.getActionCommand());
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: I would use the standard classes and use the result set to fill the table model. See this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10625471

Comment: Wouldn't that still do the same as my custom class?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, include `rs2xml.jar` in your libraries. You can find it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/finalangelsanddemons/)

In whatever action to populate your MySQL query in your `JTable` use following general idea:

```
public void sqlquery() {
    try {
        String btrResult = "SELECT BBSTBBNR, BBSTNABE, BBSTPLZ FROM BP.TBBBST WHERE BBSTNABEG = ?";
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(btrResult);
        dbConnection.setString(1, btrname);
        ResultSet rs =dbConnection.executeQuery();
        Ur_table_name.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(DbUtils.resultSetToel(rs));  //this line of code will show it in your JTable
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions for that though. I don't have a resultSetToel method, haven't seen it in the example from which I learned about the custom tables either. What would this method look like / what does it do? And as far as I see it, I need to replace the "rs" in this example with my ResultSet which would be "BTRDaoImpl.resultset", right?

Comment: What about the `resultSeToel` method? I haven't seen it in an example so far and apparently it is crucial, because right now without it, it doesn't work. With the error _"resultset cannot be resolved or is not a field"_ pointing at the `BTRDaoImpl.resultset` in said method.

Comment: resultset is imported from sql library `import java.sql.ResultSet` it will be used inside `resultSetToTableModel())` by adding the object rs, this way u will populate ur results to jtabel, do not forget to get ur js2Xml jar from sourceforge

Comment: So do I need to change the arguement for this method, which is in my case: `table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);`, into something or do I need to declare rs in my View class as well first? Because like this it gives me an error, that it obviously doesn't know the variable.

Comment: in my answer I have defined rs as an `ResultSet` object and the way u see it in  my answer works fine for me, what kind of error u get?

Comment: Mmh well I thought I could use my resultset from my other class, so `BTRDaoImpl.resultset`, but with that it gives me the error _"resultset cannot be resolved or is not a field"_.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? Try being more specific than "[...] but from there on I don't know how to progress." What do you want to do? Are the results from your query visible in the table?

Using the answer from [Paul Vargas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870248/paul-vargas) over here [Most simple code to populate JTable from ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10625471/1694043), you could start with something like this (using Java 8):

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ResultSetToTable {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new ResultSetToTable().createAndShowGui();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() throws SQLException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final TableModel tableModel = buildTableModel(getData("Audi"));
        final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ResultSet getData(final String btrName) throws SQLException {
        final String url = "jdbc:h2:/Freek/TBBBST";
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "me", "123");
        final String sql = "SELECT BBSTBBNR, BBSTNABE, BBSTPLZ " +
                           "FROM BP.TBBBST " +
                           "WHERE BBSTNABEG = ?";
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, btrName);
        return preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }

    /**
     * See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10625471/1694043
     */
    public static TableModel buildTableModel(final ResultSet resultSet)
            throws SQLException {
        int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        // Column names.
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            columnNames.add(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(columnIndex));
        }

        // Data of the table.
        Vector<Vector<Object>> dataVector = new Vector<>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Vector<Object> rowVector = new Vector<>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                rowVector.add(resultSet.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            dataVector.add(rowVector);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(dataVector, columnNames);
    }
}
```

For older versions of Java, you should be able to use this version of the `main` method:

```
public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ResultSetToTable().createAndShowGui();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit: connecting controller and table**

To make the table available outside the view, you need to convert the `table` variable in the `View()` constructor into a field (like you have done with `searchbtrname`) and create a `getTable` getter method for it (like you have done with `getSearchbtrname`). In the `Controller.actionPerformed` method you can now change `view.table` into `view.getTable()`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I'd have to execute the PreparedStatement with the SQL query a second time and therefore slowing down my program a lot?

Comment: I think the `getData` method is only called once and therefore the query is not executed a second time. You can add a println to check that. Is the example above having the same issue as your code? If the example above has issues for you, which issues do you run into?

Comment: I got a problem with the `invokeLater`-method. It is not working like in your example telling me that it needs an arguement, so Iassumed that the try-catch block should be the parameter of that method, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or an older version of Java? ["Since April 2015, Oracle is no longer post updates of Java SE 7 to its public download sites."](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml)

Comment: See the alternative `main` method above for older versions of Java.

Comment: Ah yes I'm still using Java 7 at the moment. The alternative method seems to work. Well kind of, it doesn't throw me any errors.

Comment: In that case, you can also try to call `new ResultSetToTable().createAndShowGui();` directly (so remove the 9 lines around that statement).

Comment: Ah thanks. That seemed to work. However how could I add the filled JTable to my GUI after a successful search then? As in how do I update the view with this? I know that I can't do it in my View class since that would lead to a Nullpointer exception, because no resultset exists before the search.

Comment: During initialization, you can fill the `JTable` with the results of a query. Whenever you want to update your table, you can replace the table model with a call to `table.setModel([new table model])` and your table should update automatically.

Comment: When trying to access my JTable from my Controller class however it tells me that my JTable "table" doesn't exist.

Comment: Share the code of your controller and viewer and explain your issue. It sounds like you need to make your table available to your controller, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Alright, I added the code to the end of my main post.