# Swing applications that prints the MySql Database records

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I need some help with choosing the right swing component to print the records from database, to be honest I was thinking its going to be easy with 
http://mysql.aldenwebhosting.com/JAVAtutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

BUT it doesnt cache, its just prints raw code into tabel. Can someone help me?

In its final stage, my app would download records after I press the button, then print them into some form of label, tabel,field whatever (bassicaly I dont know which swing component choose) . Next step is going to be editing one of the column parameter (binary-like yes/no) and saving it to database -  I don know if thats important - im writing it just in case, so you can see the whole "picture"

Greetings!

Comment: [see this answer you my understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset)

Answer (score 1):

To build an editable table in swing, I would suggest you to use a `JTable` with [a custom table model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and choose a `JTextField` component for your cells.

If you are not using any JPA frameworks like Hibernate, IBatis.., etc. I would recommend to use one because it helps lot in dynamic persistence in this case.