# Returning MySQL's table data to Jtable Java

Tags: java, mysql

is that possible to return all the data from MySQL table to jtable only by using array and array2D (without Vector ) ?? if yes please let me know how can i do that .. Thanks

Comment: It is possible. You will need to know the number of rows first (to initialize an array) or read the result set twice. But you should really use a `Collection`, especially a more recent `Collection` like an `ArrayList` to be specific. But that's the only answer I can give you. You need to start the code by yourself.

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset it can help you.