# When to bind TabelModel to JTable if the data is being loaded using a SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, swingworker

I am using a SwingWorker to load data from a database into my JTable through a custom TableModel using the approach suggested here : [How to fill data in a JTable with database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192764/how-to-fill-data-in-a-jtable-with-database) . If I bind my TableModel before I go on to process the ResultSet in the SwingWorker, I end up with an empty List inside the table model and JTable complains. If I bind the model after I have made a call to the SwingWorker , my JTable misses some of the callbacks that are fired by the `publish` method to update the rows in the table. Here is what my code looks like :

```
class MyTableModel{
 ResultSet rs;
 //Row is an intenral row object that is obtained after processing resultset  
 List<Row> data

 MyTableModel(){
 //initalise the row, rs etc;
 } 

 public void updateData(List<Row> r){
    data.addAll(r);
 }

 //called as a callback by another class that manages the queries
 public void processResults(ResultSet rs){
   new SwingWorker<Void,Row>(){
    doInBackground(){
     //process row by row
     publish(row);
    }
    public void process(List<Row> chunks){
       updateData(chunks);
       fireTableDataChanged();
    }
   }.execute();
 }

}
```

And this is how I am setting my table model right now

```
MyTableModel m = new MyTableModel();
//pass m as callback to the database manager which invokes processResults() on m
dbm.makeQuery("SELECT bit,pat from bot;",m);
table.setModel(m);
```

Comment: "and JTable complains"... about what??

Comment: well it is not able to get any values from the list backing the model bacuse the list is empty as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

First, I (personally) wouldn't really use `fireTableDataChanged()` method for this purpose, it will require that the `JTable` completely repaint itself (including the columns).  This is going to greatly increase the repaint times as the data set grows...

```
public void updateData(List<Row> r){
    int firstRow = getRowCount();
    data.addAll(r);
    int lastRow = getRowCount() - 1;

    fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, lastRow);

}
```