# How can I update a jTable with data gathered from a tomcat servlet?

Tags: java, swing, tomcat, jtable

I set up a tomcat server in Intellij which receives request with JSON data from a client. I want to display this data in a swing jTable. What is the best way to do this? (If it's at all possible) I already know how to convert JSON to Strings in java. My next obstacle is pushing that data to a jTable.

I have to start my Main and Tomcat separately, and I don't know how to push data to my current Java program I started with my Main Class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fill data in a JTable with database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192764/how-to-fill-data-in-a-jtable-with-database)

Comment: Start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html .

Comment: Do you want to update the table with data from the Tomcat server, or do you want to modify the contents of the table and have the changes post to the Tomcat server (to update e.g. some database, etc.)?